# Loss of data when converting file path from std::string to char*

Tags: string, visual-c++, window

Here is my code:

```
char pBuf[256];
size_t len = sizeof(pBuf);
int bytes = GetModuleFileName(NULL, LPWSTR(pBuf), len);
int len_excluding_executeable = bytes * 2;
for (int i = bytes * 2; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (pBuf[i] == '\\')
    {
        len_excluding_executeable = i;
        i = 0;
    }
}
std::string path;
for (int i = 0; i < len_excluding_executeable; i++)
{
    path.push_back(pBuf[i]);
}

path = path + "\\clang";

std::string command = "cd " + path;
const char* commandchar = command.c_str();

std::cout << command << std::endl;
std::cout << commandchar << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
cd C:\Users\source\repos\x64\Debug\clang
cd C
```

For some reason, the conversion from `std::string` to `const char*` (last 4 lines) causes a loss of data.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Use `GetModuleFileNameA` and avoid the conversion. Or change the "Character Set" project option to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" to get the mb Windows functions by default.

Comment: You should post this as an answer.